# What's the advantage of making member variable final?

Tags: java

I just know it can reduce some bugs which are because of careless.
But anything else ? 
Such as JVM efficiency and so on.

Thx all!

Comment: "careless" is one way to put it, but you try to write 10kloc industry-grade software without making a few mistakes somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest advantage is it prevents accidental writing into a variable. If a member variable is final, you will get compile time errors if your code tries to ***reassign*** that variable.

Of course, if it is an object, you could ***still*** change the contents of the object that is referred. But if you follow the principle of using `final` fields throughout your code base, then you'd have very few (or none) objects that have any member variables that are modifiable. That will ensure that the object is not mutable once created. And immutable objects prevent [a large class of errors](http://okyasoft.blogspot.com/2014/05/6-benefits-of-programming-with_5146.html). It will prevent a lot of future pain.

Answer (score -1):

It stops mistakes from happening by overwriting a variable.